# How to add tests to Ionic/Phonegap project?

Tags: angularjs, testing, cordova, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

How to add tests like karma/jasmine to existing Ionic project? I know that there are some ionic generators that also add some test stuff...

But is there something similar for existing projects?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I mean, I could do it manually it think... but generator probably would be better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are couple of good generators. The most popular one is [generator-ionic](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic). It's a Yeoman generator and it has a build-in setup for static code analysis, running unit tests and checking code coverage. Another good alternative is [generator-mcfly](https://github.com/mcfly-io/generator-mcfly). It also include infrastructure for running tests and some more UI components.